# Jest showing error on passed test on Azure

Tags: azure

When I run  `jest test` locally I see all my tests as passed.

> PASS  apps/web/customers/src/components/TelephoneDial/**tests**/TelephoneDialButton.test.tsx

When I run `jest test` in my build on Azure I get the following:

> '##[error]PASS apps/web/customers/src/components/TelephoneDial/**tests**/TelephoneDialButton.test.tsx (8.186s)

During the actual build step on azure I also see this:

> '##[error]lerna notice cli v3.13.4

While locally it shows:

> lerna notice cli v3.13.4

Why is Azure showing this output as errors?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found what's causing this issue, but switching from `Windows 2019 with VS2019` agent to `vs2017-win2016` has fixed the issue, now the output doesn't report errors.